# How do you convert or translate these zplug codes whose uncommon option into zinit language?

Tags: zsh

I read the documentation, but my translated zinit codes did not work. I found their zinit documentation a very confused.

1. I do not know which zplug's `use` is referred in zinit language, for example:

   ```bsh
   zplug "mafredri/zsh-async", from:github, use:async.zsh

   zplug "junegunn/fzf-bin", as:command, from:gh-r, rename-to:fzf, use:"*${(L)$(uname -s)}*amd64*"
   zplug "junegunn/fzf", use:"shell/*.zsh"
   zplug "peco/peco", as:command,     from:gh-r, use:"*${(L)$(uname -s)}*amd64*"
   ```

   I converted into zinit:

   ```bsh
   zinit light "mafredri/zsh-async" pick "async.zsh"
   ```

   But it gave an error: `No such (plugin or snippet) directory: mafredri/zsh-async/pickasync.zsh`. I doubt about `src` and `multisrc`. I also do not know which is similar to `rename-to`. I think as `id-as`, but I am not sure.
2. I did not find the similar option to zplug's `defer` in zinit language:

   ```bsh
   zplug "zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting", defer:2
   ```

   I am not sure if it is correct to use `depth=2` instead.
3. Another similar option I could not find on the zinit documentation, is `hook-load`:

   ```bsh
   zplug "larkery/zsh-histdb", use:"{sqlite-history,histdb-interactive}.zsh", hook-load:"histdb-update-outcome"
   ```
4. I will convert the multiple plugins into zinit's syntax `for`, I am not sure how I translate correctly:

   ```bsh
   zplug "plugins/common-aliases",    from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "plugins/copydir",           from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "plugins/cp",                from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "plugins/encode64",          from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "plugins/extract",           from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "plugins/git",               from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "plugins/golang",            from:oh-my-zsh, if:"(( $+commands[go] ))"
   zplug "plugins/npm",               from:oh-my-zsh, if:"(( $+commands[npm] ))"
   zplug "plugins/sudo",              from:oh-my-zsh, if:"(( $+commands[sudo] ))"
   zplug "plugins/systemd",           from:oh-my-zsh, if:"(( $+commands[systemctl] ))"
   zplug "plugins/urltools",          from:oh-my-zsh
   zplug "tcnksm/docker-alias", use:zshrc
   ```

   I translated into zinit:

   ```bsh
      zinit wait lucid for \
         OMZ::plugins/common-aliases \
         OMZ::plugins/copydir \
         OMZ::plugins/cp \
         OMZ::plugins/encode64 \
         OMZ::plugins/extract \
         OMZ::plugins/git \
         OMZ::plugins/golang if "[[ $+commands[go] ]]" \
         OMZ::plugins/npm if "[[ $+commands[npm] ]]" \
         OMZ::plugins/sudo if "[[ $+commands[sudo] ]]" \
         OMZ::plugins/systemd if "[[ $+commands[systemd] ]]" \
         OMZ::plugins/urltools \
         OMZ::tcnksm/docker-alias pick "zshrc"
   ```
5. I also want to know if there is a similar option similar to `zplug check` in zinit language, for example:

   ```bsh
   if zplug check "junegunn/fzf-bin"; then
     export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height 40% --reverse --border --inline-info --color=dark,bg+:235,hl+:10,pointer:5"
   fi
   ```

Comment: Your line with `zplug "larkery/zsh-histdb", ...` does not work at all for me in zplug.  How did you get it to load 'larkery/zsh-histdb' as a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Zplug's `use` is Zinit's `pick`: https://github.com/zdharma/zinit#selection-of-files-to-source-
2. Zplug's `defer` is Zinit's `wait`: https://github.com/zdharma/zinit#conditional-loading
3. Zplug's `hook-load` does not have an equivalent in Zinit, but you can solve it like this:

```bsh
zinit light-mode for pick'sqlite-history.zsh' \
  atload'autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook && add-zsh-hook precmd histdb-update-outcome' \
  larkery/zsh-histdb
```

4. In Zinit, you need to put the modifiers *before* the plugin names:

```bsh
zinit wait lucid for \
      OMZ::plugins/common-aliases \
      OMZ::plugins/copydir \
      OMZ::plugins/cp \
      OMZ::plugins/encode64 \
      OMZ::plugins/extract \
      OMZ::plugins/git \
      if"[[ $+commands[go] ]]" OMZ::plugins/golang \
      if"[[ $+commands[npm] ]]" OMZ::plugins/npm \
      if"[[ $+commands[sudo] ]]" OMZ::plugins/sudo \
      if"[[ $+commands[systemd] ]]" OMZ::plugins/systemd \
      OMZ::plugins/urltools \
      pick"zshrc" tcnksm/docker-alias
```

5. Zplug's `check` does not have an equivalent in Zinit, but you can solve it like this:

```bsh
zinit from"gh-r" as"program" for \
  atload'export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height 40% --reverse --border --inline-info --color=dark,bg+:235,hl+:10,pointer:5"' \
  junegunn/fzf-bin
```

---

### Update

I no longer use Zinit. Instead, I’ve built my own plugin manager called [Znap](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-snap).

Comment: and ```if zplug check "larkery/zsh-histdb"; then
    if [ ! -f "$HOME/.histdb/zsh-history.db" ]; then
        echo "Importe seu antigo histórico do ZSH com o repositório github.com/drewis/go-histdbimport"
    fi

    HISTDB_TABULATE_CMD=(sed -e $'s/\x1f/\t/g')
fi
``` ?

Comment: You can put everything into atload. Something like this (but you’ll need to fix the quoting):
```zinit light-mode for pick'sqlite-history.zsh' atload'autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook && add-zsh-hook precmd histdb-update-outcome; if [ ! -f "$HOME/.histdb/zsh-history.db" ]; then echo "Importe seu antigo histórico do ZSH com o repositório github.com/drewis/go-histdbimport" fi; HISTDB_TABULATE_CMD=(sed -e $'s/\x1f/\t/g')' larkery/zsh-histdb
```

Comment: Or better yet, put all that stuff from `atload` into a separate file and then `source` that file in `atload` instead.

Comment: @GustavoReis Can you please click the Accept button on this answer?

Comment: Hyvää huomenta, ole hyvä, @marlon-richert, can you update your answer to replace `zdharma` with `zdharma-continuum` and to convert my zplug/zinit into your znap? And I can I switch from `~/.local/share/zsh` to `~/.config/zsh`?

Comment: Please open a new question for that. 

Comment: done. Here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691259/i-migrating-from-zplug-zinit-to-znap-what-are-these-zplug-zinit-options-alterna