# I migrating from zplug/zinit to znap. What are these zplug/zinit options alternatives to znap?

Tags: zsh

In reference to [How do you convert or translate these zplug codes whose uncommon option into zinit language?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589183/how-do-you-convert-or-translate-these-zplug-codes-whose-uncommon-option-into-zin), I am migrating from zplug/zinit to znap in which I am interested.

I was reading the [`znap` documentation](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-snap), but I observed that `zinit` and `znap` are totally different.

I observed the option `pick` that does not exist on `znap`:

```bsh
zinit light "mafredri/zsh-async" pick "async.zsh"
```

I wonder if I would write like:

```
znap source mafredri/zsh-async
znap eval zsh-async 'curl -fsSL https://github.com/mafredri/zsh-async/async.zsh'
```

Also observe `zplug` language, using `defer`:

```
zplug "zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting", defer:2
```

I also need to defer one of plugins before another plugin, but I have no idea of how it is like in `znap`. I am thinking of sourcing the first before the second, but not sure if it is correct.

It would be interesting to want to use the conditions checking the commands but also I need to check the OS type, for example:

```
zinit wait lucid for \
      OMZ::plugins/common-aliases \
      OMZ::plugins/copydir \
      OMZ::plugins/cp \
      OMZ::plugins/encode64 \
      OMZ::plugins/extract \
      OMZ::plugins/git \
      if"[[ $+commands[go] ]]" OMZ::plugins/golang \
      if"[[ $+commands[npm] ]]" OMZ::plugins/npm \
      if"[[ $+commands[sudo] ]]" OMZ::plugins/sudo \
      if"[[ $+commands[systemd] ]]" OMZ::plugins/systemd \
      OMZ::plugins/urltools \
      pick "zshrc" tcnksm/docker-alias
```

And can I switch from `~/.local/share/znap` to `~/.config/zsh`?

Comment: There's no point to individual tags for all these plugin managers. The *only* questions in any of them so far have been by you, and even there were like 4 all together in two years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```bsh
znap prompt  # This is how you "defer".

() {
  local -a plugins=( 
      common-aliases copydir cp encode64 extract urltools
      ${commands[go]:+golang} 
      ${commands[npm]:+npm} 
      ${commands[sudo]:+sudo} 
      ${commands[systemd]:+systemd} 
  )
  znap source ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh plugins/$^plugins
}

znap source tcnksm/docker-alias zshrc  # This is how you "pick".

znap source mafredri/zsh-async
znap source zdharma-continuum/fast-syntax-highlighting
```

---

By the way, I would recommend *not* using `mafredri/zsh-async`. Zsh has [built-in features for doing async](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-launchpad/blob/7fd0ffd14c9a82ae0dec130dcf6e60237e54f1fb/.config/zsh/functions/precmd#L12). You don't need a plugin for that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll remove the unnecessary plugin. And about the plugins `junegunn/fzf` (failed), `peco/peco` (failed)? About `wfxr/forgit` (failed), `Aloxaf/fzf-tab` (failed), `larkery/zsh-histdb`, `plugins/dircycle`, `plugins/z`, `supercrabtree/k` and `tarrasch/zsh-bd`? I want just to know if they are unnecessary for `znap`.

Comment: What do you mean with "(failed)"?

Comment: Znap doesn't make any plugins unnecessary. I don't really understand your question. :)

Comment: If you find that there are plugins that Znap cannot load, then please [start a discussion on the Znap repo](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-snap/discussions).